# Understanding Microsoft Azure AD On-Behalf-Of (OBO) flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

FE ->(token_a) Middleman ->(token_b) DownstreamServiceA

My understanding is that, for the `Middleman` to make API calls to `DownstreamServiceA`, it needs to exchange for `token_b` using `token_a`. I tried to simulate this behaviour in postman. But I am unable to exchange for `token_b` using `token_a`. I get the following error

```
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '{my-middleman-clientid}'
```

On the Azure Portal, I have configured the FE API permission to have access the exposed API scope of `DownstreamServiceA` & `Middleman`. Granted admin consent on behalf of my organisation users at that too.

**Getting token_a**

```
POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type:password
client_secret: foobar
client_id: my-fe-clientid
username: awesome
password: bar
scope: api://{MiddlemanId}/Middleman.All
```

**Exchange for token_b**

```
POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id: my-middleman-clientid
client_secret: foobar
scope: api://{DownstreamServiceAId}/ServiceA.all
assertion: {token_a}
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

May I know what am I doing wrong? My understanding is that my FE needs to request and grant permission for the `DownStreamServiceA` scope upfront, which I did with an admin grant on the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have granted FE access to Middleman, and you've granted FE access to DownstreamServiceA, but you may not have granted Middleman access to DownstreamServiceA.

There are a few ways you can do this, as described in [Granting consent for the middle-tier application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#gaining-consent-for-the-middle-tier-application):

- In Middlemanm, declare FE as a "known client application" (`knownClientApplications` in the manifest/Application object) and trigger "combined" consent by requesting for `scope=openid api://{MiddlemanId}/.default` at FE. The consent prompt will include all the permissions both FE and Middleman require, and the grants recorded will be correctly set for FE to Middleman and Middleman to DownstreamServiceA, as needed.
- In DownstreamServiceA, declare Middleman as a "preauthorized" application (App registrations > Expose an API > Authorized client applications). The consent prompt for FE will *not* include any of the Middleman to DownstreamServiceA permissions, which will be considered already granted.
- At Middleman, manually grant consent for the required permissions. This is sometimes the simplest approach, if you are an admin of the tenant. (E.g. App registrations > API permissions > Grant admin consent)

Comment: Explicitly wiring of FE access to DownstreamServiceA on the Azure Portal is not necessary am I right? I just need to edit the manifest for Middleman and request for `scope=openid api://{MiddlemanId}/.default` at FE.

Comment: I just tried the above step and there is not interactive prompt at the FE for `DownstreamServiceAId/ServiceA.All` scope

Comment: @Gavin I didn't quite understand either of your two comments, could you please elaborate?